# mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exists

Tags: raspbian, usb, hard-drive, mount

I bought a Raspberry Pi and installed Raspbian and transmission.
I want to connect my USB hard drive to save there the transmission's downloads.
The HDD is formatted in FAT32, Windows recognizes it correctly.
When I try to mount it in /dev/sda1 it prompts me:

`mount: special device /dev/sda1 does not exists`

fdisk finds only `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

I also tried adding

```
/dev/sda1      /mnt/usb     vfat      uid=pi,gid=pi     0     0
```

to my /etc/fstab.

Can someone help me?

I tried mounting an NTFS-formatted USB flash drive and it mounts correctly.

Comment: Why does fstab not work? what errors do you get with it?

Comment: Add the output from `lsusb` while the HDD is plugged in.  If that command is not found, install usb tools: `apt-get install usbutils`.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43477/can-not-make-directory-on-my-usb-disk-connected-raspberry-pi-2/43482#43482

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the disk powering up? A USB HDD may require lots of current. I suggest you use a powered USB hub for the disk.

Comment: I tried with another HDD (FAT32) alimented, and it works fine. The fact is the don't-working HDD powers up when I turn on the Raspberry, but I'm not able to mount it.
My 3.0 HDD, instead, doesn't even power up.
In the afternoon I'm buying a powered USB hub then.

Comment: Can you post the output of 'dmesg' and 'cat /var/log/syslog' ?

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally I get windows USB storage devices that do not have a "1st" partition and have to be mounted without the partition specifier so in fstab I have

```
/dev/sdc        /mnt/sdc    auto        user,noatime        0 1
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/sdc1   auto        user,noatime        0 1
```

and mount them with either

```
mount /mnt/sdc1
```

or

```
mount /mnt/sdc
```

if /dev/sdc1 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo blkid` and if you can't see your HDD that's mean it still not powered up. The Pi's USB ports only have output ~500mA as default so it might not enough for your HDD.

In this case you have to increase current output of those USB ports. Add `max_usb_current=1` to `/boot/config.txt` then reboot the Pi :)

Comment: I advise against maxing the current to the USB ports, a powered USB hub is a much better option.

Comment: with this specific case : Raspbian + Transmission + one HDD.
I cant see why it shouldn't. That HDD may draw more than 1.2A? Probably not :)